# Embedding code in SQL functions in SAP HANA

Tags: hana

What programming languages does SAP HANA support in embedding code to run within the HANA cluster similar to how you would write your own SQL functions to run inside an RDBMS, or your own code to run on a Hadoop cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two options here. The first thing would be **Stored Procedures**. These are actually pretty common in other databases like MySQL or DB2. You can create a new procedure with `CREATE PROCEDURE`. More information on this can be found in the [HANA Documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/d467407519101484f190f545d54b24/content.htm). The supported languages for this are [SQLScript](http://help.sap.com/hana/sap_hana_sql_script_reference_en.pdf) and [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29).

Another thing that should be mentioned is the **XS Engine**. Every HANA (I think) has the XS Engine built in. This is basically a JavaScript frontend for your HANA. You can use the XS Engine to write JavaScript APIs, interfaces and applications directly on your HANA using JavaScript. Get started [here](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?3762b229a4074fc59ac6a9ee7404f8c9.html).

Comment: Thanks! I think the XS Engine is available in all recent releases. It's more of a javascript backend though... that runs your javascript code on the HANA server, thus closer to the data than any client code. Correct me if I'm wrong about that....

Comment: What still baffles me about it all, is how does XS Engine code operate on a cluster spanning more than one SAP HANA e.g. on EC2. I saw little addressing the point of how to write XS code that runs across the instances... I mean this would call for something like mapping and reducing to boil down to a single final result set... (hence the reference to 'cluster' in my question).

Comment: Yes you are correct about the XS Engine. And I can only assume that the HANA will do all the heavy lifting for XS when there is more than one node.

Comment: In that case it's a really smart engine, because my javascript would not handle concurrency in any way unless there's some api doc for that. I am not sure the engine is really _that smart_ to automagically interpret regular javascript code for distributed operation across a cluster (when the data involved spans more than one instance in the cluster, at least)

Comment: Maybe my notion of what a HANA cluster is, is just incorrect... maybe only one instance in a cluster runs the XS Engine, and then my code just runs on that instance, whereas the concurrency is handled by implicitly whenever my XS code calls for data from the cluster. In that case, my code won't really run "on" the cluster, it will run just on one node.

Comment: I think it depends on how your cluster is connected but i believe that the XS engine usually runs on the master node only and the master will then distribute the javascript queries accordingly to the other nodes. I usually work with with single-node HANAs so I am not the most reliable source for this, but I believe that's how it works

Comment: I could wildly guess it would only distribute the data access calls from the script and not the script, as the script being run on all nodes would mean that data from multiple scripts needs to be aggregated.. perhaps a topic for a new specific question.

Comment: Yes, the script itself is not distributed but the query calls are

Comment: Excellent. Do you happen to have a link to where you checked/confirmed that?

Answer (score 0):

SAP HANA offer XS Engine to integrate and develop apps. Its a good way, considering the network traffic, authentication and security.

The XS Engine is 'server' which allows .html, .css, .js, .csv, images files and .xsjs.

The last one type is a kind of javascript which run as a back-end language, creating connection with database.